# Alter all attributes printed in views on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My rails application only reads data on it's database. There's no save. 
Mostly all my views are a form with a few fields to filter my search and a table printing every column's value. Something like that:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th> Col1 </th>
  <th> Col2 </th>
  <th> Col3 </th>
  ...
 </tr>
<% Model.all.each do |model| %>
 <tr>
  <td> <%= model.col1 %> </td>
  <td> <%= model.col2 %> </td>
  <td> <%= model.col3 %> </td>
  ...
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

There's over 50 models each with 10-20 fields, almost 100 tables. It's all very straightforward.

Now my client asked me that when any cell is empty (the data is null or '') he wants it to print '-' instead of the blank cell on the table

At first I thought about something like this on my application_helper.rb:

```
def avoid_empty(object)
 if object == nil or object == "" 
   return "-"
 else
   return object
 end
end
```

and everywhere on my views I would just change

```
 <%= model.col1 %>
```

to

```
 <%= avoid_empty(model.col1) %>
```

but I actually have 2659 lines like that. I'm not sure it's the healthier approach.

Is there any way I can change it everytime I try to print any value from those models that I could go through that method or something similar first, without having to change every single one of my 2659 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the power of ruby's meta-programming and `ActiveSupport::Concern`.

Create a model extension module to overwrite the `getter` of all columns dynamically. Below code can do that:

```
module ModelExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  # To exclude some columns
  EXCLUDE_COLUMNS = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']

  included do
    (self.column_names - EXCLUDE_COLUMNS).each do |col|
      define_method col do
        self[col].blank? ? '-' : self[col]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Include this module in each model to get '-' instead of blank or nil. To include model, you can do:

```
class MyModel
  include ModelExtension
end
```

Comment: This seems exactly what I was looking for, but it's not working. I'm not sure if it's because I'm on an oracle database.

It's giving me this error when calling self.column_names:

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedConnectionException at /gestao_pessoas/membros/membros_ativos
"DESC gestao_pessoas_tb_membro_ativos" failed; does it exist?


. If I remove your module, it returns correctly an array with the column names. So it's probably the module that is bugging it

I'm using Rails 4
and the gems: 'ruby-oci8' and 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.5.6'

Comment: @HelioBorges I've tested that in rails 3 & PostgreSQL. Never used Oracle though. Can you provide the details of `self` inside `included` block? Some details like, the value of `self` and `self.class`. Information of error backtrace will also be helpful. You can provide backtrace in GitHub gist.

Comment: Also, try including this module in some other model, and check if it works there.

Comment: I managed to get it working

The describe method inside OracleEnhancedConnection class from module ActiveRecord and module ConnectionAdapters was getting the wrong tablename. The actual table name is 'tb_membro_ativo' not 'gestao_pessoas_tb_membro_ativos'. 'gestao_pessoas' is my module where the class 'tb_membro_ativo' is in.

So I used the power of ruby's meta-programming to fix that :). Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Good to know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can monkeypatch `NilClass`.

```
class NilClass
  def to_s
    '-'
  end
end
```

Everytime you invoke, say, `nil.to_s`, it will print `'-'`. If you type `puts nil` in the console, will print `-`. Try the following example:

```
class NilClass
  def to_s
    '-'
  end
end

foo = nil
foo.to_s  #=> '-'
puts foo  #=> -
```

In your case, all occurrences of empty (`nil`) attributes will output `-` in the view when trying to print (and, be warned, in other parts of your application too).

PS.: `#to_s` returns a string representing the instance object.

Comment: Never monkeypatch NilClass especially with metods from other classes. It's very error prone and you would not even be informed about this error.

Answer (score 1):

A solution maybe
The Null Object Pattern

Null Object is an object with some default behavior that implements the same interface as an other object that might be used in a given case. Ok, cool, but how can we apply it to the example below? Let's start with the user method:

```
 def user
   @user ||= User.find_by(email: email) || NullUser.new
 end
```

And now we can implement NullUser:

```
class NullUser
  def name
    "Anonymous user"
  end
end
```